# How to determine the length of a char * for a generice logger function?

Tags: c, logging

i am writing a reusable logging module for a firmware prototype. I have a logger api which has a wrapper function `void LogWithNum(eLogSubSystem sys, eLogLevel level, char * msg, int * number)`

In this wrapper function, a system specific write function is called. Could be UART for example, or a display driver...

All system write / transmit functions somehow require the length in bytes of a message though. And my wrapper function only gets a a char * to the message it should send. See here for example, where my wrapper calls the systems UART transmit function:

```
void LogWithNum(eLogSubSystem sys, eLogLevel level, char * msg, int * number)
{

     UARTDRV_Transmit(handle, char * msg, int msglen);
}
```

How can i derive the length of any message so i can pass it properly to the underlying transmitting function?

I dont want to use large librarys since i am on a uC  and want to save space.

Comment: If `msg` contains only ASCII characters, then maybe `strlen()`?

Comment: Can't you use `strlen()` or just write a simple loop that would increment `char *` and a counter until it meets `NUL`?

Comment: Not clear: your example is sending `number` not `msg`

Comment: Sorry my bad, picked a code example where i only send the number.

Comment: The inner function should be something like: uart_send(char* msg, int msglen)

Comment: So edit your question. BTW, as others already commented, is `msg` a pointer to [tag:c-strings]?

Comment: Yes, msg is a pointer to c strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different ways to solve your problem:

Using [strlen](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) to calculate the [c-string](/questions/tagged/c-string) length

```
void LogWithNum(eLogSubSystem sys, eLogLevel level, char * msg, int * number)
{
     UARTDRV_Transmit(handle, msg, strlen(msg));
}
```

Or looping through the [c-string](/questions/tagged/c-string) until null terminator

```
void LogWithNum(eLogSubSystem sys, eLogLevel level, char * msg, int * number)
{
     while (*msg != '\0')
        UARTDRV_Transmit(handle, msg++, 1);
}
```

Or calculate the `msg` length without `strlen` combining solutions above

```
void LogWithNum(eLogSubSystem sys, eLogLevel level, char * msg, int * number)
{
     int msg_length = 0;

     while (*msg++ != '\0')
        msg_length++;

     if (msg_length > 0)
        UARTDRV_Transmit(handle, msg, msg_length);
}
```

Comment: Or you could loop through to find the length (manually, rather than using `strlen()`) and make just the one UART call (depending on how that works, one may be preferable to the other).